# Prevent withSpinner from appearing by default

Tags: r, shiny

I use `withSpinner()` to indicate to the user that calculations are being made. However, there is no default output on my app, i.e the user has to click on a button to compute the output.

`withSpinner()` automatically appears on the app. The problem is that, since the user has to click on a button to show the output *for the first time*, the spinner is misleading because the user could think that calculations are being made whereas they're not. Is there a way to prevent the spinner from appearing by default?

Reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("foo", "foo", 0, 10, 5),
  actionButton("button", "button"),
  textOutput("text") %>% 
    withSpinner()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$button, {

    output$text <- renderText({
      input$foo
    })

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When you run the app and do nothing, there is the spinner at the center whereas it shouldn't be displayed as long as the button is not clicked.